# understanding vite in localhost

Tags: vite

I'm new to using vite with react as a build tool. I usually use CRA and I only see a handful of requests in my network tab. With Vite there are hundreds. Is this normal and how does Vite work in regards to loading all these imports differently than Create React app.

In the example below this is just a small window of all the chunks its loading.

Example:
[image]

Comment: Vite's documentation covers this rather well: https://vitejs.dev/guide/why.html#slow-server-start. TLDR: Vite uses native ESM rather than bundling all deps